# jQuery animate sidebar problems

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, sidebar

I am using an animate sidebar that scroll together with the window scrolling and stop when it reach the footer.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var jQuerysidebar = jQuery("#sb"),
    jQuerywindow = jQuery(window),
    offset = jQuerysidebar.offset(),
    sbh = jQuerysidebar.height(),
    footer = jQuery("#footer").offset().top;


 jQuerywindow.scroll(function() {
    if ( jQuerywindow.scrollTop() > offset.top  ) {
        if (jQuerywindow.scrollTop() + jQuerysidebar.height() < footer) {
            jQuerysidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: jQuerywindow.scrollTop() - 8
            });

        }
    } else{
         jQuerysidebar.stop().animate({
            marginTop: 0
        });
    }
});

});
```

Since the sidebar height is > that the window height, I can't easily get access to the bottom of the sidebar: when i scroll down it also goes down...

I would like the sidebar start scrolling only after that i reach its end... so far I have been able to get this result only partially:

```
if ( jQuerywindow.scrollTop() > jQuerysidebar.height()  ) {
```

As it is obvious, after that the scrollTop value is > than the sidebar height, it keeps scrolling again... so this code works only once :D

Is there a better way to make the sidebar scrolling only after that i reach its end?

I have tried also other solutions but i got for my every new attempt some different problem. (I am new in using jquery...)

Thanks for your help:)

Comment: Will it work if you set `position: relative` to the `#sb`, then switching out `marginTop` with just `top` ? Check out this example I made: http://jsfiddle.net/KWn8e/

Comment: I tried but i didn't get the hoped result. The sidebar still shift down before i reach its end.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I tried to rewrite the code, and this is the result:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var jQuerysidebar = jQuery("#sb"),
    jQuerywindow = jQuery(window),
    offset = jQuerysidebar.offset(),
    sbh = jQuerysidebar.height(),
 footer = jQuery("#footer").offset().top;


 jQuerywindow.scroll(function() {

  // here It check the win scrolltop to be > than sidebar height + its offset.top value 
 // and in the same time that the sidebar height*2 (+offset.top) is not bigger than the footer offset top.
 // if this is true, than marginTop = sidebar height
    if ( (jQuerywindow.scrollTop()  > sbh+offset.top) & (((sbh*2)+offset.top) < footer)) {

           jQuerysidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: sbh
                    });
  // if the sidebar height*2 (+offset.top) is bigger than the footer offset.top value, than
  // the marginTop will be set = to the sidebar height - the difference between the sidebar height*2 and the footer (to this last value is also removed the sidebar offset.top)
  // 10 is for to add some more space between the sidebar and the footer
    }else if ((jQuerywindow.scrollTop()  > sbh+offset.top) & (((sbh*2)+offset.top) > footer))  { 
           jQuerysidebar.stop().animate({
             marginTop: (sbh + (footer-(sbh*2)) - (offset.top+10))
        });

    } else {  jQuerysidebar.stop().animate({
            marginTop: 0
        });
    }

  // here it does the same thing as above but for values of scrolltop > than sidebar height*2 (+ offset.top value)
            if  (jQuerywindow.scrollTop() > (sbh*2)+offset.top & (((sbh*3)+offset.top) < footer)) {
        jQuerysidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop:  sbh*2                });

        }else if ( (jQuerywindow.scrollTop()  > (sbh*2)+offset.top) & (((sbh*3)+offset.top) > footer)) { 

          jQuerysidebar.stop().animate({
             marginTop: ((sbh*2) + (footer-(sbh*3)) - (offset.top+10))
        });

    }

})

});
```

The result is that the sidebar will scroll only afterI reach its end without continuing to move.

It works... but it is a bit long and there is probably a better way to get the same result.

I can repeat the code for each new sidebar scrolling (here, the sidebar scrolls only 2 times).